# Django internationalization files in apps folders

Tags: django

Is it possible to create separate *.mo and *.po files for every application? Let`s say that I add new external app to my project and I don`t want to localize it but use some translations which, are contained in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short - yes, it's possible and recommended (it helps keeping order in the translations). Simply:

1. Execute `manage.py makemessages` in the root directory of your Django app to create `.po/.mo` files for that particular app.
2. Store the [translation files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/i18n/#message-files) will be in stored in `$APPPATH/locale/<language>/LC_MESSAGES/django.(po|mo)` directory (so inside the app directory).